# JSON stored into an array not callable by specific index

Tags: arrays, json

I am trying to develop an app for my fantasy baseball league to use for our draft (we some kind of quirky stuff all the major sites don't account for) - I want to pull some player data to use for the app by using MLB's API. I have been able to get the response from MLB, but can't do anything with the data after I get it back. I am trying to store the JSON into an array, and if I console.log the array as a whole, it will give me the entire chunk of data, but if I try to call the specific index value of the 1st item, it comes back as undefined.

```
let lastName = 'judge';
let getData = new XMLHttpRequest;
let jsonData = [];
function getPlayer () {
    getData.open('GET', `http://lookup-service- 
prod.mlb.com/json/named.search_player_all.bam? 
sport_code='mlb'&active_sw='Y'&name_part='${lastName}%25'`, true)
    getData.onload = function() {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            jsonData.push(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        }
    }
    getData.send();
    console.log(jsonData);
}
```

When I change the above console.log to console.log(jsonData[0]) it comes back as undefined. If I go to the console and copy the property path, it displays as [""0""] - Either there has to be a better way to use the JSON data or storing it into an array is doing something abnormal that I haven't encountered before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jsonData` array will be empty after calling `getPlayer` function because XHR loads data asynchronously.

You need to access the data in `onload` handler like this (also changed URL to HTTPS to avoid protocol mismatch errors in console):

```js
let lastName = 'judge';
let getData = new XMLHttpRequest;
let jsonData = [];
function getPlayer () {
    getData.open('GET', `https://lookup-service-
prod.mlb.com/json/named.search_player_all.bam?
sport_code='mlb'&active_sw='Y'&name_part='${lastName}%25'`, true)
    getData.onload = function() {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            jsonData.push(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            // Now that we have the data...
            console.log(jsonData[0]);
        }
    }
    getData.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First answer from [How to force a program to wait until an HTTP request is finished in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760319/how-to-force-a-program-to-wait-until-an-http-request-is-finished-in-javascript) question:

> There is a 3rd parameter to XmlHttpRequest's open(), which aims to
>   indicate that you want the request to by asynchronous (and so handle
>   the response through an onreadystatechange handler).
>
> So if you want it to be synchronous (i.e. wait for the answer), just
>   specify false for this 3rd argument.

So, you need to change last parameter in `open` function as below:

```
getData.open('GET', `http://lookup-service- 
prod.mlb.com/json/named.search_player_all.bam? 
sport_code='mlb'&active_sw='Y'&name_part='${lastName}%25'`, false)
```

But from other side, you should allow this method to act asynchronously and print response directly in `onload` function.