# How do I send a value from Javascript to PHP that will not be changed?

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, debugging

I have function that is running multiple times and executing a PHP file. I do, however, want to make sure the functions does not interfere with each other.

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    functionName(i)
}

function functionName(number){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        }
    };
    var PageToSendTo = "phpFile.php?";
    var MyVariable = number;
    var VariablePlaceholder = "name=";
    var UrlToSend = PageToSendTo + VariablePlaceholder + MyVariable;
    xhttp.open("GET", UrlToSend, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

This is how my code looks so far, how do I change it so that the next iteration of the function does not effect the previous one?

phpFile.php

```
<?php
require '../notWebsite/dbh.php';
session_start();

$variable = $_GET['name'];

$sqlInsertClass = "INSERT INTO class (className) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlInsertClass)) {
    header("Location: ../Website.php?error=InsertError");
    exit();

} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $variable);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    exit();
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a program to wait until an HTTP request is finished in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760319/how-to-force-a-program-to-wait-until-an-http-request-is-finished-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't think so because that would slow down the js side and I just want the reocurring function to not effect the calculations of its previous recursions. As an example: loop start, phpFile (number 1) starts with name as 1; but then when the function fires again function with i=2 changes the value of 'name' to 2. Which I fear would effect phpFile(number 1)s calculations.

Comment: In that case you might want to edit your question and clarify what you mean by `not effect the calculations`.  The PHP file as shown is just inserting records - no matter how many of those you do, how fast, or in what order, they won't affect each other.  If there's more to it, you'll need to explain what and why they might impact each other.

Comment: Agreed with @Don'tPanic. At OP: This *Which I fear would effect phpFile(number 1)s calculations* needs further explanation from you. MySql is quite capable of handling your requests no matter how fast they are. Its a stable db with mechanisms already in place for what needs to be done. Therefore your *I do, however, want to make sure the functions does not interfere with each other* is over paranoia.